# Replace ends of string in eclipse

Tags: python, regex, eclipse, logging, replace

I am trying to refactor a large source base in a company I work in. Instead of using the print function in python 2.7x I want to use the logger function.
for example:
print "Sample print %d" % timestamp
With logger.info("Sample print %d" % timestamp)

so basically, I want to remove the print , and insert what remains into parentheses and logger.info (Ill assume all current prints are INFO until a full refactor is possible).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Search for `(^\s+)print (.*)$`
Replace with `$1logger.info($2)`

Python should complain pretty fast about all the places where a `print` goes over more than a single line. You'll have to fix those places manually.

Note: This skips comments

The alternative is to look into the source for `2to3.py` which replaces `print ...` with `print(...)` to convert code from Python 2 to 3.

Comment: Please Accept an answer when it resolves your question. Do so by clicking the gray checkmark next to the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer